# Extract information from HTML documents using the commandline

Tags: html, linux, command-line

I'm using `wget` to download an HTML page and extract information from. Specifically I want to turn this:

```
<a href="/312728/" title="The 10 Best Goals ever">
<a href="/671921/" title="Golf at its best">
<a href="/371285/" title="Football Legends">
<a href="/576903/" title="Boxing Legends">
```

into this and save as a txt file.

```
/312728/The 10 Best Goals ever
/671921/Golf at its best
/371285/Football Legends
/576903/Boxing Legends
```

I've tried:

```
wget --quiet -O - http://some-site.com | grep -o '<a href="/?/" title="?"> > new.txt
```

but that didn't gave me the desired results.

Comment: `grep` or regular expression in general are not the right tool to extract information from markup languages. There are tons of examples how to do it the right way in the internet. However, you'll also find tons of wrong examples using regular expressions. I've rephrased your question a bit. I hope that opens your mind a bit for solutions different from `grep`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changing the `grep` to `egrep` for some finer regex abilities, you can do something like:

```
wget --quiet -O - http://some-site.com | egrep -e '<a href="\/[0-9]*\/" title="[:alnum:]*'
```

Which should return:

```
<a href="/312728/" title="The 10 Best Goals ever">
<a href="/671921/" title="Golf at its best">
<a href="/371285/" title="Football Legends">
<a href="/576903/" title="Boxing Legends">
```

Then, using `awk` we can delimit that stuff by double-quote and pick out the parts you want to return:

```
wget --quiet -O - http://some-site.com | egrep -e '<a href="\/[0-9]*\/" title="[:alnum:]*'  | awk -F'"' '{print $2$4}'
```

Which should return this:

```
/312728/The 10 Best Goals ever
/671921/Golf at its best
/371285/Football Legends
/576903/Boxing Legends
```

Which you could redirect to a text file like this:

```
wget --quiet -O - http://some-site.com | egrep -e '<a href="\/[0-9]*\/" title="[:alnum:]*'  | awk -F'"' '{print $2$4}' >> mytextfile.txt
```

Comment: no what i wrote with wget does nothing its not returning anything  thats why i need help to write it  and there are lots of them not just 4

Comment: can anyone please help

Comment: It's hard to say since I have no idea what your html looks like. Maybe for your grep: `egrep -e '<a href="\/[0-9]*\/" title="[:alnum:]*'` ?

Comment: thanks i got something back but they all still look like this  <a href="/671921/" title="Golf at its best">

Comment: Sounds like you just need to pipe to that `awk` bit I included in the answer. Something like: `wget --quiet -O - http://some-site.com | egrep -e '<a href="\/[0-9]*\/" title="[:alnum:]*' | awk -F'"' '{print $2$4}'`

Comment: JNevill your a star that last one worked  thank you very much

Comment: Glad to hear it's working! I've updated the answer to reflect the changes that came from this convo.